# Cocos2d and ios5 : ccTouchesBegan

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

My question is that, I was using this method before it was working perfectly, today am trying to do it in another project. This is the code

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPos = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:[touch view]]];
    CCLOG(@"( %d , %d )",touchPos.x,touchPos.y);
}
```

What I'm getting is strange output the output is always similar to this ( 0 , 1081286656 )

I would love if someone could help me

Best Regards
Ahmed

Comment: You are using the wrong string format specifiers. `CGPoint`'s `x` and `y` fields are `CGFloat`s. You need to use `%f`.

Comment: Yeah sure you can, that's mostly because I do develop on both Qt and Objective-C ;p and that's what happens ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the strange output you are getting is that you are using the wrong [string format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). `CGPoint`'s `x` and `y` fields are `CGFloat`s. You need to use `%f` instead of `%d` (which is for integers).